# How to add authentication to the proxy forward trafficserver

Tags: proxy, authentication

Sorry as I add authentication to a server proxy for trafficserver already investigate and is loading the plugin basic-auth.c I did according to this tutorial https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/4.2.x/sdk/getting-started/a-simple-plugin.en.html create the plugin follow the tutorial but it doesn't work I hope your help as to authenticate use trafficserver because squid proxy does not work has an error when using it on my server thank you for your help I've seen that ATS fails to load the plugin, use trafficser server 5.2.3